# How to write to a hash with map without over-writing hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash, and I'm writing to it with `map` thus:

```
%snp = map {$_ => 1} @snp
```

but the problem is that this overwrites the hash.

`map {$snp{$_} => 1} @snp`  should work, but doesn't

I know that I can use `foreach` to iterate through `@snp` but I want to learn Perl better.

How can I use `map` to ***add*** the values of `@snp` to a hash, rather than overwrite it?

For example, the original hash %snp starts out as

```
{
    rs1333042    1,
    rs17591786   1
}
```

I want to map array values, e.g. this single value array `@snp`:

```
[
    [0] "rs7545860"
]
```

so that `%snp` will become

```
{
    rs1333042    1,
    rs7545860    1,
    rs17591786   1
}
```

how can I accomplish this with `map`?

Comment: To learn Perl better, I'd recommend not using `map` in a void context (treating it like a foreach).  You could use a hash slice for this: `@hash{ @array } = (1) x @array`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
my %h;
map { $h{$_} = 1 } @snp;
```

Comment: I messed up, I had `=>` instead of `=`

Comment: I did not downvote, and I agree, this answer is correct and should not be downvoted. Some has commented that `map` is the wrong tool here, but the OP expressly asked for a solution based on `map` and not `for`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a hash, and you want to add keys to it without overwriting it, just do that.

```
my %snp = ( foo => 1, bar => 1 );
my @snp = ( "baz", "boz" );

map { $snp{$_} = 1 } @snp;
```

This will add keys to the hash without overwriting it. So long as the hash keys are unique. If you have duplicate values, it will overwrite the keys.

I thought that was what you tried, and said did not work, but then I realized you used the arrow operator `=>` instead of assignment operator `=`

```
map {$snp{$_} => 1} @snp;    # wrong
```

This will just create a list of key/value pairs which it will return in void context and be discarded. If you use assignment instead, it will alter the hash as you wanted.

> I know that I can use **foreach** to iterate through @snp but I want to learn Perl better.
>
> How can I use **map** to add the values of @snp to a hash, rather than overwrite it?

As has been noted in the comments, you can use `for` (`for` and `foreach` are aliases for the same function). Which is actually the better solution, in my opinion.

```
$snp{$_} = 1 for @snp;
```

Comment: or `$snp{$_}=1 for @snp`, which avoids `map` in void context

Comment: @mob I know, but he expressly said he knows he can use foreach, but wants to learn Perl.

Answer (score 2):

You can append to your hash like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my %s = (
    rs1333042  =>  1,
    rs17591786 =>  1,
);

my @snp = qw(rs7545860);

%s = (%s, map { $_ => 1 } @snp);

print Dumper(\%s);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'rs1333042' => 1,
          'rs17591786' => 1,
          'rs7545860' => 1
        };
```

Keep in mind that the hash keys must be unique.